# Bluetooth outgoing files log

Tags: bluetooth

I had let someone use my phone and they had bluetoothed some files to their own phone and im trying to find what they had sent so i know whether or not to worry about any private stuff being exposed.. my phone is an lg optimus f60 running 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

In my Android 4.2.1 the default **Bluetooth share** app records the sent/received files in a history which can be accessed by launching Bluetooth app → tap Menu key and choose **Show received files**. There you can see all the **Downloaded** as well as **Uploaded**(sent from your phone) files.

My Bluetooth app doesn't provide any option to delete those entries so I'm rest assured to know what was sent/received using my device's Bluetooth, unless the data was cleared from **Settings → Apps**.

---

That said, the solution is demanded for Android 4.4.x, and in this case the solution is bit lengthy.

**BT share** app in my Android 4.4.2 and 5.0  records the sent/received files in a database file.

#### If you've root access:

1. Download an SQlite viewer/editor from Play Store (I prefer [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor&hl=en)),
2. Launch it and find **BT share** or whatsoever the name is in your Android under **Apps** tab,
3. Choose the database (`btopp.db` in my device),
4. Open the tables there (`btopp` in my case). One of the tables would be having the entries of sent/received files,
5. If the device is really yours then you would know by a mere look  what was sent/received from and into your device. Anyhow, the value `0` in column `Direction` indicates **Sent** and `1` indicates **Received**.

   There's more here. Received file entries start with `content:` in the `Name` column while Sent ones start with `file:`.

#### If you don't have root access:

1. Take a [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/96277) of **BT Share** app using `adb backup <PARAMS>`,
2. Extract the backup using [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/) and locate the `.db` file under `databases` in the extracted content.
3. You can either follow the aforesaid steps 1-4 with exception of using **Files** tab and not **Apps** tab in step 2, or
4. You may download a software like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and follow aforesaid (under **root access** section) step 3 and 4 .

We're good to go!

Comment: Note that nothing in the solution would possibly work if that user cleared data from **Settings -> Apps**.